# Piping JShell REPL through tee

Tags: pipe, tee

If possible, I would like to pipe JShell REPL through tee in the following manner:

```
jshell | tee "~\jshell-`date +'%d_%m_%Y__%H-%M-%S'`.log"
```

The command executes and Shell launches but no file materialises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file does materialise. Just not where you expect it (but in the current directory instead and with a `~` as the first character of its name). You can easily see the problem running

```
echo tee "~\jshell-`date +'%d_%m_%Y__%H-%M-%S'`.log"
```

So the solution is

```
jshell | tee ~/"jshell-`date +'%d_%m_%Y__%H-%M-%S'`.log"
```